# Error:No callback function was given?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt

It is showing the error in the node modules.Now how should I do this?

```
C:\Users\Lenovo\newcontactapp\server\app\node_modules\bcrypt-nodejs\bCrypt.js:621
                throw "No callback function was given."
                ^

No callback function was given.
```

I have used `bcrypt-nodejs` API in order to hash the password and save it to database.

A portion of my code where I have used `bcrypt` API.

```
bcrypt.genSalt(9, function (err, salt) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            user.password = hash;
            console.log('changed user password',+JSON.stringify(user.password));
            next();
        });
```

Need Help.

Answer (score 0):

I have missed a cb function in `bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function (err, hash)` it should be like :

`bcrypt.hash(data,salt, progress,cb)` where,

data:[Required]

salt[Required]

progress:callback function

cb: callback function

link:[bcrypt-nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs)